# Delete UItableViewCell after one day

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a requirement from client where I would like to delete the data after one day or 24 hrs. We are loading all the user data in UITableView. I wanted to know if there is any method that I can use to delete the tableview cell after 24-48 hrs? Thank you for your help!

Comment: you are using any DB to maintain user data?

Comment: if you are using any DB.. just fire one notification, based on timer and call one method in that by using query are some thing clear the data from DB table and get new data to array and reload the table

Comment: Yes I do have a DB. I will give this a try. Thank you very much!